# encryption , String to Byte conversion

Tags: c#, type-conversion

I have a string and i changed it to hex values , so i want to store them in the Byte array , but it gives me error of "Input String is not correct format". here is my code :

```
        byte[] PlainText = new byte[16];
        byte[] MasterKey = new byte[16];
        string input = "Hello";
        char[] values = input.ToCharArray();
        int i =0;
        foreach (char letter in values)
        {
            int value = Convert.ToInt32(letter);
            string hexout = String.Format("{0:X}", value);
            PlainText[i++] = Convert.ToByte(hexout);
        }
```

Comment: Why bother with the int and string?  Just convert directly to byte and be done with it.

Comment: it should be converted to int , i used the letter variable directly and it did convert nothing .

Comment: I am not saying use the letter variable directly, I am saying convert it directly to byte.  Replace the three lines in your loop body with `PlainText[i++] = Convert.ToByte(letter);` or even `PlainText[i++] = (byte)letter;`

Answer (score 1):

Change your intial code

```
    byte[] PlainText = new byte[16];
    byte[] MasterKey = new byte[16];
    string input = "Hello";
    char[] values = input.ToCharArray();
    int i =0;
     string hexout=string.empty;
    foreach (char letter in values)
    {
        int value = Convert.ToInt32(letter);
        hexout+= String.Format("{0:X}", value);

    }
    plaintext=StringToByteArray(hexout);
```

for converting hex to byte array

```
          public static byte[] StringToByteArray(String hex)
         {
      int NumberChars = hex.Length;
      byte[] bytes = new byte[NumberChars / 2];
       for (int i = 0; i < NumberChars; i += 2)
       bytes[i / 2] = Convert.ToByte(hex.Substring(i, 2), 16);
       return bytes;
      }
```

or

For parsing long string

```
   public static byte[] StringToByteArray(String hex)
 {
int NumberChars = hex.Length/2;
 byte[] bytes = new byte[NumberChars];
 using (var sr = new StringReader(hex))
{
for (int i = 0; i < NumberChars; i++)
  bytes[i] = 
    Convert.ToByte(new string(new char[2]{(char)sr.Read(), (char)sr.Read()}), 16);
 }
 return bytes;
}
```

Comment: when i executed your firs code , it declares me an error :"Could not Find any recognizable digit" on the line 'bytes[i/2] = convert...'

Comment: @user3639111 now try this one

Comment: ok , so how can i verify that Plaintext array is now filled with same data just in Byte format? When i Console.Write nothing happens .

Answer (score 0):

```
var bytes=System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(yourString);
```